# Write more beautiful math equations, like a professional book

Tags: math-mode, formatting, equations

I want to write math equations more "beautiful". My equations are shown as follows:

> [image: equation]

The vector looks ugly and disproportionate. And I like that they look it this way:

> [image: equation]

The vector looks good, in place and the letters clear and well defined.

Comment: Use `esvect` package or bold faced characters.

Comment: Conversely I find the latter very ugly and Word-like. So professional doesn't mean *usual*

Comment: Why does the `r` in the latter have an arrow to represent it's a vector when it is already in boldface? It's quite confusing. The *professional* way of doing it is writing `\vec{r}`, which usually wouldn't let you something like `\vec{\mathbf r}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A first note:
*The equations shown below represent an identical copy of the second expression shown by the OP. Since they are not correct, according to the accepted vector notation, I apologize in advance.*

From the first equation it can be easily recognized that the `\usepackage{palatino}` and `\usepackage{mathpazo}`has been used, because of the typical italic setting, so with a basic MWE the bold faced variant could be defined as you like:

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
%
\begin{document}
\[
\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}=%
\mathrm{d}x\hat{\mathbf{i}}+%
\mathrm{d}y\hat{\mathbf{j}}+%
\mathrm{d}z\hat{\mathbf{k}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Here is the (I hope it's beautiful enough) example output:

> [image]

---

**EDIT:**

This workaround has been done by substituting `mathpazo` with `newtxmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
%
\begin{document}
\[
\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}=%
\mathrm{d}x\hat{\mathbf{i}}+%
\mathrm{d}y\hat{\mathbf{j}}+%
\mathrm{d}z\hat{\mathbf{k}}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image]

As you can see the plus and equal sign are smaller by default. To change directly these operators inside the old font would require some kind of sorcery that at the end won't match a default setting.

Comment: These days, `mathpazo` is only one of several LaTeX packages that provides Palatino-based text and math fonts. There's also `pxfonts`, `newpx[text,math]`, and the TeX-Gyre `tgpagella` family, to name but three alternatives to `mathpazo`...

Comment: Looks great! It's possible to change size of the plus sign?

Comment: @Kiyoshi you could do this by changing the basic font to `mathpazo` to `newtxmath`, in such a way it'll be more roman-like.

Comment: @Mico You're right, but to date I still have to find some time to search and implement those new font packages inside my documents...

Comment: I like Palatino for text but I like newtxmath for equations, any solution?

Comment: @AndreaL. - A quick note: `newtx[math,text]` loads a `Times Roman`-type font family. To get a `Palatino` font (which is what the OP may want), be sure to specify `\newpx[math,text]`.

Comment: @Kiyoshi - I suppose you could specify `\usepackage{newpxtext,newtxmath}` to get your wish. However, the x-heights of the two font families aren't exactly the same, so the result may not be all that great.

Comment: @Mico I'll make an addendum...

Comment: @Mico - Ok, thanks for explain me the problem with fonts.

Comment: What is the font of the second equation? Is a physic book, authored by Serway and Jewett.

Comment: @Kiyoshi the font is called Times Roman, loaded *only for the math* by `\usepackage{newtxmath}`. If you want it even for the text, simply add `\usepackage{newtxtext}`.

Answer (score 24):

You don't mention how the ugly-looking "r with arrow above" was created, but it looks like it was done with `\overset{r}{\to}`. If one uses `\vec` instead, one gets more normal looking arrows.

I would also recommend using "dotless" `i` and `j` unit vectors.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\begin{document}
$ d\vec{r} = dx\hat{\imath} + dy\hat{\jmath} + dz\hat{k} $
\end{document}
```

Comment: Even further, I would recommend dotless bold i and j.

Comment: @Ingo - I didn't go quite that far, i.e., I didn't explicitly recommend using **bold** dotless i's and j's, because I couldn't tell what the OP's method is for using boldface for the vectors (including `\imath`, `\jmath`, and `k`, with or without a `\hat` symbol).

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[d]{esvect}

\newcommand\dd{\textrm{d}}

\newcommand\xhat{\,\hat{x}}
\newcommand\yhat{\,\hat{y}}
\newcommand\zhat{\,\hat{z}}

\newcommand\ihat{\,\hat{\imath}}
\newcommand\jhat{\,\hat{\jmath}}
\newcommand\khat{\,\hat{k}}

\newcommand\xu{\,\boldsymbol{x}}
\newcommand\yu{\,\boldsymbol{y}}
\newcommand\zu{\,\boldsymbol{z}}

\newcommand\iu{\,\boldsymbol{i}}
\newcommand\ju{\,\boldsymbol{j}}
\newcommand\ku{\,\boldsymbol{k}}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\begin{align}
\dd\vv{r} &=\dd x\xhat+\dd y\yhat+\dd z\zhat\\
\dd\vv{r} &=\dd x\ihat+\dd y\jhat+\dd z\khat\\
\dd\boldsymbol{r} &=\dd x\xu+\dd y\yu+\dd z\zu\\
\dd\boldsymbol{r} &=\dd x\iu+\dd y\ju+\dd z\ku
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OH my ghost, they look very professional, don't they?