# How to make a vector bold and italic inside an equation

Tags: fonts, math-mode, equations, bold, italic

I want all my equations to be in italics and the vectors to be bold as well. When I write the following LaTeX code it gives italic equations:

```
\begin{equation}
F = kx
\end{equation}
```

But when I re-write to make the vectors bold, the vectors become bold but don't stay italic anymore:

```
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F} = k\mathbf{x}
\end{equation}
```

How can I keep the whole equation in italics with vectors appearing as bold?

Comment: How about [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139593/19356)?

Answer (score 15):

You could use the [bm](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bm) package and its command `\bm`. One of the very nice things about  this package is that `\bm` works equally well on letters and symbols; thus, one doesn't have to remember to use `\mathbf` on letters and `\boldsymbol` on symbols. Another nice aspect -- especially useful for your setup -- is that you get ***bold-italic*** rather than **bold-upright** output.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\bm{F} = k\bm{x}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax%don't use this line in your production
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{F} = k\, \boldsymbol{x}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: a clean solution. Why to use this rare extra package `bm` when the `amsmath` package is so common? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the \bm command, from the bm package, which seems preferable in a number of cases. See:
[\bm package versus \boldsymbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/bm-package-versus-boldsymbol)