# Can you make it pretty?

Tags: equations

Just for fun. Can you make this equation as pretty as possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{bm}
%

\begin{document}

    $\delta\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\mathcal{L}(\bm{q},\bm{\dot{q}})dt=0$

\end{document}
```

It should be pretty when printed on a whole page. So be careful to the spacings between the symbols.

Comment: It is already pretty.  What exactly are you seeking?  If the question is how to scale it to a whole page, a `\scalebox` can be employed.

Comment: Define 'pretty'. Please provide compilable code and explain what you actually want. Code fragments are not very helpful.

Comment: Some might say adding ducks to your equation would be pretty and fun. :)

Comment: @Troy that's kinda the point. let's see what people think a beautifully-written equation is

Comment: @shamalaia You should address the other comments, not mine. "Let's see what people think" is primarily opinion-based and is not really suitable in a QnA setting of TeX.SE.

Comment: This is just asking for opinions, then, and so not a suitable question for this site. Your question needs to make clear what would constitute a good answer.

Comment: Have a look at Related Q [Write more beautiful math equations, like a professional book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139587/15717), [Suggest a “nice” font family for my basic LaTeX template (text and math)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59702/15717) and [What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58098/15717), Pick the one which looks pretty for your eyes... :)

Comment: Define `\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}` and use `\diff t` instead of `dt`; it should be `\dot{\bm{q}}`; define `\newcommand{\vari}{\mathop{}\!\delta\check@for@int}` and `\newcommand{\check@for@int}{\@ifnextchar{\int}{\mkern-6mu}{}}` (requires `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`). Then try `\vari\int...`.

Comment: already many things to learn from a primarily opinion-based question. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Throw away that unspeakably ugly (IMHO) font, and sort out the horizontal and vertical spacing...

The end result is entirely subjective, of course.

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{erewhon}
\usepackage[utopia,cmintegrals]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}
%

\begin{document}

    $\displaystyle\delta\mkern -8mu \int_{t_1}^{\mkern 1mu t_2} \mkern -15mu \mathcal{L}(\bm{q},\bm{\dot{q}})\mkern 2mu dt=0$

\end{document}
```